# Where do East End / Gangster slang terms for numbers relating to money originate?

Tags: etymology, slang, vernacular

Words like 'monkey', 'pony', 'ton' and so on are used by East End villains and Cockneys to denote numbers - ton is one hundred for example. Examples abound in popular culture (The Krays, Only Fools and Horses, Guy Ritchie movies). Where do these terms come from? And how could the words possibly connect to the amounts?

Comment: I think the last two questions are ungrammatical. But, as non native, I'm unsure on how they should be correct.

Comment: @Carlo_R.: There's nothing wrong with the last question. In the second to last, OP had simply failed to type the word "come", which I've just added. *Your* last sentence should read *"But, as **a** non native, I'm unsure <del>on</del> how they should be **corrected**"*

Comment: See also http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23090/do-to-pony-up-and-to-pungle-come-from-the-same-latin-root

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[monkey = five hundred pounds (£500). Probably London slang from the early 1800s. Origin unknown. Like the 'pony' meaning £25, it is suggested by some that the association derives from Indian rupee banknotes featuring the animal.](http://www.learnenglish.de/slang/moneyslang.htm)

The origin of *ton* supposedly comes from the fact that a ton is a measurement of 100 cubic feet of capacity (for storage, loading, etc).

That link above gives a good summary of what's known about British slang money words and expressions. I will just say that I'm "semi-Cockney" myself. Like most Brits, I know the value of a *pony* and a *monkey*, but I've seldom if ever heard them used except "facetiously". *Ton*, on the other hand, is relatively common (though not so common as the US import *grand*).

Comment: A tun is around 256gallons (depending on wine or beer) which is 33-34cu ft

Comment: @mgb: Yes, although I see OED says it was 252 "old wine-gallons", and also that *Now, for the purposes of registered tonnage, the space of 100 cubic feet.* I didn't mean to imply the word *"ton"* itself derived from 100 cu/ft - effectively, it's the other way around. I just meant that's why it became slang for 100 (pounds, miles per hour, etc).

Comment: @fumblefinegrs - yes gross tonnage for ships is 100cu ft, and it was fixed in the mid C9 which is just right for slang https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gross_register_tonnage

Comment: I rather like the US usage of `large` for a thousand too.

Comment: @5arx: This writer wants to make sure the reader understands the units... [Bellarosa said, “It cost me five large to get the paint stripped off this room. Then another five for the books. Books go for ten bucks a foot.” “Excuse me?” “There's five hundred feet of bookshelf. Books are ten bucks a foot. So that's five large](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=yg39xo2dNiAC&pg=PT93&lpg=PT93&dq=%22cost+me+five+large+to+get%22&source=bl&ots=_-I7EGwKSd&sig=2iD3VKPNfsxWDjdesh7hY2je6a0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=K0MYULGfGoLB0QXW6YCoDg&ved=0CDQQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22cost%20me%20five%20large%20to%20get%22&f=false).